# Save in two or more models at the same time with form_valid

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

Regards,

I need to save and the same time in two or more models the data that I submit in a form, how can I valid this with form_valid? I trying this but with no success:

```
class PEPropietarioView(UpdateModelMixin,UpdateView):
    model = Propietario
    form_class = FormPropietario
    success_url = '/'
    template_name = 'productores/PE/propietario.html'

    def form_valid(self,form):
        admin = Administrador()
        enc = Encargado()
        admin = form.save()
        enc = form.save()
        return super(PEPropietarioView,self).form_valid(form)
```

How can I achieve save the data that I submit in FormPropietario and the same time in Administrador and Encargado model?

Answer (score 1):

Add a method to your FormPropietario form :

```
class FormPropietario(forms.Form):

    ...

    def save_relateds(self):    
        admin = Administrador.objects.get_or_create(**self.cleaned_data)
        enc = Encargado.objects.get_or_create(**self.cleaned_data)
        return True
```

And then call it :

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.save_relateds()
    return super(PEPropietarioView,self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply... But it does not work, it create the Administrator and Encargado but all the fields empty, only saves Propietario because its in the model attribute. Any other possible solution?

Comment: It works. Thanks, although `create` it no use to me because as you can see I have an UpdateView, I mean.. I need to update or create that model, Im trying with   `admin = Administrador.objects.get_or_create(**self.cleaned_data)` but nothing happens... But in general, your answer works.

Comment: In your `form_valid` method ?

Comment: yes, I already fixed. Was my fault, a syntax error. But is not working as I need it. I dont know if apply in this thread. Because instead         `admin = Administrador.objects.create(**self.cleaned_data)` I need `get_or_create`, but always create a new one. Any clue?

Comment: I edited my question, it may be fixed (removing id or pk from the instance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78024/discussion-between-dfrojas-and-charlesthk).